# Sqlite3, Python, Aiogram, help

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

можно ли как то выбрать таблицу users и в ней выбрать всех пользователей и всем им изменить столбец Balance

Пользуюсь Sqlite3, Python, Aiogram
Заранее спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Если я прав, то метод в sqlite "UPDATE"  без параметра WHERE изменяет все значения столбца всех юзеров на какое-то нужное нам значение:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE users SET Balance = ?',(Balance))
conn.commit()
```